# Is there any Gesture Recognizer event to rotate pie chart clockwise?

Tags: objective-c, ios4, core-plot, xcode4.2

I want to rotate pie chart through gesture recognizer event when i drag pie chart clockwise\anticlockwise not through selectIndexPieChart event .

Please advise .

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Look at [UIRotationGestureRecognizer](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIRotateGestureRecognizer_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIRotationGestureRecognizer). - When the user moves the fingers opposite each other in a circular motion, the underlying view should rotate in a corresponding direction and speed.

There is a `CPTGraphHostingView` in core-plot SDK which contains all your plots. Attach that gesture recognizer to this view and see result.

Comment: Thanks beryllium , i want to use single touch for rotation in circular motion .

Comment: See `UIPanGestureRecognizer` in this case

Comment: i tried UIPanGestureRecognizer  but this is for simple dragging in any direction , i want to drag in circular direction so please advise..

Comment: Just check what direction was dragging. Something like this: if endPoint.x-startPoint.x>10 and endPoint.y-startPoint.y<10 then rotate it to left/right. There is no existing solution with gesture recognizers for get it, try yourself.

Comment: Its not working. Please suggest .

Comment: Can you advise me something for the me ???

Comment: I can't see your code.. it's a very specific task, try to search in another threads.